# JSDoc and JavaScript singleton documentation

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a JavaScript singleton defined as:

```
/**
 * A description here
 * @class
 */
com.mydomain.ClassName = (function(){

/**
 * @constructor
 * @lends com.mydomain.ClassName
 */ 
var ClassName = function(){};

/**
 * method description
 * @public
 * @lends com.mydomain.ClassName
*/
ClassName.prototype.method1 = function(){};

return new ClassName();

})();
```

No warnings are printed in verbose mode (-v), but the documentation reports only "com.mydomain.ClassName()" with "A description here" as description... how can I generate documentation for ClassName's methods too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved! :)

```
  /**
 * A description here
 * @class
 */
com.mydomain.ClassName = (function(){

/**
 * @constructor
 * @name com.mydomain.ClassName
 */ 
var ClassName = function(){};

/**
 * method description
 * @public
 * @name com.mydomain.ClassName.method1
*/
ClassName.prototype.method1 = function(){};

return new ClassName();

})();
```

I just replaced @lends with @name!

**UPDATE: the right approach in order to have the full documentation is the following:**

```
/**
 * A description here
 * @class
 */
com.mydomain.ClassName = (function(){

var ClassName = function(){};

/**
 * method description
 * @memberOf com.mydomain.ClassName
*/
ClassName.prototype.method1 = function(){};

return new ClassName();

})();
```